# How do I remove the new environment commands that were created by the virtualenvwrapper script?

Tags: terminal, python, gnome-terminal, bashrc

I've installed and run `virtuarenvwrapper.sh` to try to configure an alternate version of python on my system.  This script has placed somewhere a series of commands that are now executed whenever I open `gnome-terminal`.  Now, when I open a terminal I see:

```
bash: which: command not found...
bash: -m: command not found...
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks. 

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenv has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON= and that PATH is
set properly.
user@localhost ~]$
```

I want to remove these commands but I can't find out where they are.  I've looked in:

- `~/.bash_profile`
- `~/.bashrc`
- `/etc/bashrc`

The commands run on my user terminal as well as root's terminal.  What other places can one put commands to run upon opening a terminal?

Comment: The bits about deactivating the environment and then removing in this A..do they help in your case? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103719/how-to-install-easy-install-using-non-default-python-interpreter-on-centos/103722#103722

Comment: @slm, the virtual environment wasn't successfully created so when I run `rmvirtualenv`, I get similar errors to what I get when opening a terminal.

Comment: I think I had a similar issue when writing up that A 8-). I had to spend much of an evening using `grep` and ripping out all the cruft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit was a symlink at `/etc/profile.d/virtualenvwrapper.sh`

The solution was to either remove that symlink or, better, uninstall the package:

```
yum remove python-virtualenvwrapper
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a little function I use whenever I'm trying to track something like this down:

```
grep_bash(){
    grep -H "$@" ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/bash.login \
        /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile /etc/environment /etc/profile.d/* \
        /etc/pam.d/* 2>/dev/null
}
```

If you add that to your `~/.bashrc` you can use it to look for any string in your bash's initialization files.

Note, however, that the likeliest case here is that your `~/bashrc` or whatever is sourcing another file and *that* is the problematic one. So, try looking for the word `source` or the `.` character:

```
grep -wE '\.|source' ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/bash.login \
        /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile /etc/environment /etc/pam.d/*\ 
         /etc/profile.d/* 2>/dev/null
```